# How is Cantor’s diagonal argument useful when it doesn’t interact with the entire set of values?

Tags: set-theory

Assume we are able to create a list of every unique combination of binary values with infinite position places. If each value has infinite position places then there are 2^infinite combinations of unique values. To demonstrate this at a smaller scale look at 2 bits. There are 2 position places, but 2^2 combinations. Because the length of the values (infinity) are not equal to the number of combinations (2^infinity), the diagonal method will only interact with a segment of the set, not the entire set. Again to demonstrate at a smaller scale:

1. 00
2. 01
3. 10
4. 11

Using the diagonal method on this set of values will only interact with half of the entire set. Starting from the top left, after flipping the bits you get 10, which is outside of the section of the set that the diagonal interacts with, but is still inside the set as a whole. You can use the diagonal method on any section of the set, and you will always get a value that is outside of the section the diagonal interacts with but that is still within the entire set.

What exactly does Cantor’s diagonal argument prove if it isn’t interacting with the entire set? It makes sense that the diagonal of flipped bits will be a value outside of the examined section, but that doesn’t mean that it is somehow some uncountable value beyond the confines of the set as a whole. Am I missing something? Maybe I’m misunderstanding something about the diagonal method?

Comment: It proves that you can't make a list of all possible infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s.

Comment: That is precisely the point! If the number of binary sequences were countable, then the diagonal *would* interact with the entire set. And we can’t have that.

Comment: I agree that would be true assuming that the length of each sequence was equal to the quantity of all sequences.

Comment: @littleO Given ZFC, we can make a list of all possible countably infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s. But the length of that list would be uncountable. Cantor's diagonal argument doesn't foribd having such a list, but it forbids its length being countable, that's all.

Comment: @zuhair What is the definition of a "list"? It's not a standard term and I didn't actually define it. Maybe I should have instead said "It proves that there is no bijection between the set of all positive integers and the set of all infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s", in order to be perfectly precise.

Comment: @littleO, Ah! I see. I thought a list is just a sequence, i.e. a function from some ordinal domain usually without a repetition, so its like a bijection from some ordinal domain. The length of the list is its domain. But some people further demand them to be countable, which would serve your purpose. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is quite unusual to allow a list to have uncountable many lines. The terminology "list" in such cases seems to be unlucky.

Answer (score 2):

OK, lets call the number of positions places in each unique binary value as the *width* of the list, while the total number of binary values as the *length* of the list.

Now when you have a list $L$ of all binary values each with infinitely many position places, lets say $\aleph_0$ many places, then you are having a list whose width is $\aleph_0$ and its length is $\beth_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Now a diagonal can be raised on ANY sub-list of $L$ whose length is $\aleph_0$, this sub-list would be square shaped (since both its width and lenght are equal, both are $\aleph_0$).

Given the above, then Cantor's argument will show that any square sub-list $Q$ of $L$ will have a diagonal binary value that is ***in*** $L$ but *outside* $Q$

This shows that the whole list $L$ canNOT be square, i.e. its length cannot be $\aleph_0$, since if it is, then we can raise a diagonal over it and this would be a binary value with $\aleph_0$ many position places, and this binary value won't be in $L$, which contradicts $L$ being the list of all possible binary values with $\aleph_0$ many position places. Or if you like to phrase the result in another way: Cantor's diagonal would show that the length of list $L$ is strictly bigger than the length of ANY square sub-list of it, and thus it is not countable.

So Cantor's argument clearly establishes that the list of all those binary values is uncountable, i.e. cannot be a square list. That's all.

Comment: I understand that the diagonal method proves that the length is greater than the width. What I don’t understand is why this makes it uncountable? We know both the length and the width, so if we applied the diagonal method starting from the first and last digits of every line wouldn’t we encounter every possible  value in the whole set L?

Comment: @PerpetualFool, if you understand that the length is *greater* than the width, then this mean that the length is uncountable, because the width is $\aleph_0$ (i.e. the size of the set of all natural numbers), then if the length is $> \aleph_0$ then this by definition mean its uncountable. I don't see how this is not understandable?

Comment: @PerpetualFool, what do you mean by "line" in your comment?

Comment: I guess I don’t understand why the size of the set of all natural numbers is equal to the width and not the height? Every binary combination represents a natural number, so if it is possible for a unique binary combination to exist outside of the square set that supposedly contains all natural numbers, then this means that the square doesn’t actually contain all natural numbers.

Comment: By line, I mean each binary combination. The first combination is the first line, the second combination is the second and so on.

Comment: @PerpetualFool, because that's how we specified the list in the first place, we said that each binary value has *infinitely* many position places, and we said exactly that they have $\aleph_0$ many position spaces, and this mean by definition, that each binary value has as many position spaces as the naturals are, and since we defined  the *width* of $L$ as the size of position spaces in each binary value, then the width of $L$ is the same size of the nautrals. Notice that each binary value is intended to represent a *real*, so the height of $L$ is equal to the size of the reals.

Comment: @PerpetualFool, YOU said that "every binary value represents a natural number", that's wrong, it doesn't, some of them do, but not all of them. Notice that each binary value has *infinitely* many position spaces, so only those that end with a tail of zeros would represent a natural number. That's why the height of $L$ is the size of the binary values or the size of all possible infinite combinations of the naturals, and those are not necessarily the naturals. With some work we can prove that the height of $L$ is the same as the size of the *reals*.

Comment: @PerpetualFool, if each line means a binary combination (you named it as binary value) , then why did you say the first and *last* digit of EVERY *line*, we are assuming that all binary values (i.e. all lines) have *infinitely* many position spaces, so there is no last digit in any of those *lines*.

Comment: I’m certain that’s not how binary counting works. Show me a single example where a binary combination is not a natural number. From 2^0 place to 2^infinity place, every binary combination will represent a natural number.

Comment: The last digit of each binary combination is at position 2^infinity, just as the first digit is at position 2^0.

Comment: @PerpetualFool, take for example the binary representation of $\pi$ with removal of the decimal point, that would be an binary value with countably infinite many position places, that doesn't represent a natural number, it won't even represent a rational number.

Comment: @PerpetualFool, I was not speaking about binary combinations having an $\aleph_0$ position space, $L$ was taken to be confined to binary combinations of naturals in which each digit is at a finite distance from the first digit, so those lines (binary combinations) you are speaking about are not in $L$ from the outset by the definition of $L$

Comment: @PerpetualFool, the whole diagonal method applies the diagonal to *every* square "sub-list" of $L$, so we actually have a repeated process, for each square sub-list we apply the diagonal argument, and so on..So definitely it encounters all the items in the list, i.e. the entir set of values. We won't establish the uncountability of $L$ by applying the argument on one square sub-list of $L$, of course that's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

It forbids the existence of a bijection between $\mathbb{N} $ and $2^\mathbb{N} $.

For it to make sense in your example, you need 4 bits. (since you need a square to take a diagonal that "covers" every line)

Comment: That’s what I’m getting at, the diagonal method requires a square to contact every line in the set, but 4 bits isn’t a square either, that’d be a 4 by 2^4 grid. If there isn’t an equal number of rows and columns then you can’t confirm that the diagonal value is unique from the entire set.

Comment: @PerpetualFool The only reason you **know** that it’s not a square is because of Cantor’s theorem that the cardinalities are not equal.  You might think you know that without Cantor, but you can’t rely on small-number intuition for infinite cardinalities.  For instance, the finite subsets of $S$ strictly outnumber $S$ when it’s finite, but when $S$ is infinite then they are equicardinal.